# Understanding Array.reduce() and scope

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use array.reduce to add an array. If I encapsulate my code in a function it breaks:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function add(arr){
    arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, i, fullArr){
        return prev + curr
    })
}

var result = add(test)
var result2 = arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, i, fullArr){
    return prev + curr
})
console.log(result)    // undefined
console.log(result2)   // works, 21
```

Why does the first result get undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hehe, I've done this one before... You have to `return` from `add`

```
function add(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, i, fullArr) {
        return prev + curr;
    });
}

console.log(add(test)); // => logs 21
```

Comment: @ConnorLeech There's no function being returned. `add` returns the result of `arr.reduce`, which is a number in your case

Comment: yeah not what I meant. It's early. will accept your answer 4 minutes